# Transfer files from SFTP to FTP using scp command

Tags: scp

How can I transfer files from SFTP to FTP using the scp command?
I have tried this : `scp -P21 /folder/file user@domaine.com:/folder`
But it is not working! It gives that error:

> connection lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scp` command doesn't support the FTP protocol, so you'll need to use an FTP client.

The top answer to [this question, "How to upload one file by FTP from command line?"](https://superuser.com/q/323214/4542), suggests invoking the FTP client like this:

```
$ ftp -n <<EOF
open ftp.example.com
user user secret
put my-local-file.txt
EOF
```

That is, instruct the FTP client to connect to `ftp.example.com`, authenticate, and upload `my-local-file.txt`, all in a single shell command.

---

Alternatively, you can use curl.  [This page](https://everything.curl.dev/ftp/upload) goes into more detail, but basically you would run:

```
curl --user user:secret --upload-file my-file.txt ftp://ftp.example.com/folder/
```

Note the trailing slash in the URL - that makes curl upload the file into that folder with the same name as the original.  If you don't add a trailing slash, e.g. `ftp://ftp.example.com/folder`, curl thinks that you want to rename the file to `folder` when uploading.

If you don't want to specify the username and password on the command line, you can create a "netrc file":

```
machine ftp.example.com login user password secret
```

(Don't forget to restrict permissions with `chmod 600 ./my-netrc-file`!)

And tell curl to use it with the option `--netrc-file`:

```
curl --netrc-file ./my-netrc-file --upload-file /folder/file ftp://ftp.example.com/folder/
```